gettign json.decoder.JSONDecodeError at random
I have implemented this function given by this answer: https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/70155/33457
when I run this code sometimes it goes well while most of the time it returns this error:
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

The funny thing is that whether it goes through or returns this error seems to be totally random? Why is that?
I have tried to figure out if my headers is the problem but I don't know
Se my full code here;
import requests

def get_symbol_for_isin(isin):
    url = 'https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v1/finance/search'

    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.109 Safari/537.36',
    }

    params = dict(
        q=isin,
        quotesCount=1,
        newsCount=0,
        listsCount=0,
        quotesQueryId='tss_match_phrase_query'
    )

    resp = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers, params=params)
    data = resp.json()
    if 'quotes' in data and len(data['quotes']) > 0:
        return data['quotes'][0]['symbol']
    else:
        return None

apple_isin = 'US0378331005'
print(get_symbol_for_isin(apple_isin))

The return should be 'AAPL'

Whatever is in the response is not JSON, that's what the error tells you. Do you check for errors (4xx/5xx)?

debug it, Print resp when it fail

You should check the status_code of the response.  If the server is returning a 4xx error, it probably won't be JSON.
def get_symbol_for_isin(isin):
    url = 'https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v1/finance/search'

    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.109 Safari/537.36',
    }

    params = dict(
        q=isin,
        quotesCount=1,
        newsCount=0,
        listsCount=0,
        quotesQueryId='tss_match_phrase_query'
    )

    resp = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers, params=params)
    if resp.status_code != 200:
        return resp.reason
    data = resp.json()
    if 'quotes' in data and len(data['quotes']) > 0:
        return data['quotes'][0]['symbol']
    else:
        return None

